# Trying to multiply 2 column values together for each row & print the total sum of all the rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My goal is to work out the total value of stock.

```
Table name: Stock
Column names: cost(representing an items cost), s_count(representing quantity).
```

cost multiplied by s_count would give the total value of each item.
how would i go about multiplying these columns together, then totaling the results for all rows together to get the total amount?

```
$selectstock=$db->query("SELECT * FROM stock");
$result = $db->query('SELECT SUM(s_count) AS value_sum FROM stock'); 
$rowes = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
$sum = $rowes['value_sum'];
$result2 = $db->query('SELECT SUM(amountfailed) AS value_sum FROM stock'); 
$rowes2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2); 
$sum2 = $rowes2['value_sum'];
$uparts = mysql_num_rows($selectstock);
$value = // how do i do this?
print "<h3>Stock overview..</h3><br />
<div><p><br />
Amount of unique parts in stock: {$uparts}<br />
total quantity of stock: {$sum}<br />
Current value of all stock: {$value}<br />
Amount of parts failed: {$sum2}<br />";
```

if this was the table below...
example:-

```
| id | cost | quantity |
| 1  |  20  |     5    |
| 2  |   5  |    10    |
| 3  |   2  |     2    |
| 4  |  10  |     1    |
| 5  |   7  |     3    |
```

then `$value` would need to be 20*5 + 2*10..etc

so $value would return 185.

Comment: 20*5 i get, but 2*10... eh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT SUM(s_count*cost) AS value_sum
FROM stock
```

Comment: if you mean `$value = $db->query("SELECT SUM(s_count*cost) AS value_sum FROM stock");` then $value would print as `Resource id #13`